# How to play PES+H264 stream via ffmpeg/ffplay command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a h264 video stream wrapped as pes packets, while playing on my embedded hardware, the screen blurred.

So I want to verify the accuracy using ffmpeg command, but how, is anyone can help? that will be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately, providing code examples and errors:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Eaither wrap the PES in TS or remove the PES and use raw annexb